# Docker with Python and PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I some questions about Docker. I have very little knowledge about it, so kindly bear with me.

I have a python script that does *something* and writes into a PostgreSQL DB. Both are run on Docker. Python uses `python:3.8.8-buster` and PostgreSQL `postgres:13`. Using `docker-compose up`, I am able to instantiate both these services and I see the items inserted in the PostgreSQL table. When I `docker-compose down`, as usual, the services shut down as expected. Here are the questions I have:

1. When I run the container of the PostgreSQL service by itself (not using `docker-compose up`, but `docker run` then `docker exec`) then login into db using PSQL, it doesn't take the db name as the db name mentioned in the docker-compose.yml file. It takes `localhost`, but with the username mentioned per the docker-compose.yml file. It also doesn't ask me for the password, although it's mentioned in the Dockerfile itself(not *docker-compose.yml* - for each of the `services`, I have a *Dockerfile* that I build in the *docker-compose.yml*). Is that expected? If so, why?
2. After I've logged in, when I `SELECT * FROM DB_NAME;` it displays 0 records. So, basically it doesn't display the records written in the DB in the previous run. Why's that? How can I see the contents of the DB when it's not up? When the container is running (when I `docker-compose up`), I know I can see the records from PG Admin (which BTW is also a part of my `docker-compose.yml` file, and I have it only to make it easier to see if the records have been written into the DB).
3. So after my script runs, and it writes into the db, it stops. Is there a way to restart with without `docker-compose down` then `docker-compose up`? (On VSCode) when I simply run the script, while still `docker-compose` is `up` it says it cannot find the db (that's mentioned in the docker-compose.yml file). So I have to go back and change the db name in the script to point `localhost` - This circles back to the question #1.

I am new to docker, and I am trying my best to wrap my head around all this.

Comment: Please ask only one question per question, and make sure it is about programming!

Answer (score 0):

1. This behavior depends on your specific setup. I will have to see the `Dockerfile`(s) and `docker-compose.yaml` in order to give a suitable answer.
2. This is probably caused by mounting an anonymous volume to your `postgres` service instead of a [named volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-volume-with-docker-compose). Anonymous volumes are not automatically mounted when executing `docker-compose up`. Named volumes are.

Here's a `docker-compose.yaml` example of how to mount a named volume called `database`:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

# Defining the named volume
volumes:
    database:

services:

    database:
        image: 'postgres:latest'
        restart: 'always'
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: 'admin'
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'admin'
            POSTGRES_DB: 'app'
        volumes:
            # Mounting the named volume
            - 'database:/var/lib/postgresql/data/'
        ports:
            - '5432:5432'
```

3. I assume this depends more on the contents of your script than on the way you configured your docker `postgres` service. Postgres does not shut down after simply writing data to it. But again, I will have to see the `Dockerfiles`(s) and `docker-compose.yaml` (and the script) in order to provide a more suitable answer.

Comment: Hi. Very sorry for the delay. Please give me 24 hours. I'll share the details.

Answer (score 0):

If you `docker run` an image, it always creates a new container, and it never looks at the `docker-compose.yml`.  If you for example

```
docker run --name postgres postgres
docker exec -it postgres ...
```

that starts a new container based on the `postgres:latest` image, with no particular storage or networking setup.  That's why you can't use the Compose host name of the container or see any of the data that your Compose setup would normally have.

You can use `docker-compose up` to start a specific service and its dependencies, though:

```
docker-compose up -d postgres
```

Once you do this, you can use ordinary tools like `psql` to connect to the database through its published `ports:`

```
psql -h localhost -p 5433 my_db
```

You should not need normally debugging tools like `docker exec`; if you do, there is a Compose variant that knows about the Compose service names

```sh
# For debugging use only -- not the primary way to interact with the DB
docker-compose exec postgres psql my_db
```

> After my script runs, and it writes into the db, it stops. Is there a way to restart it?

Several options:

- Make your script not stop, in whatever way.  Frequently a Docker container will have something like an HTTP service that can accept requests and act on them.
- Re-running `docker-compose up -d` (without explicitly `down` first) will restart anything that's stopped or anything whose Compose configuration has changed.
- You can run a one-off script directly on the host, with configuration pointing at your database's published `ports:`.

It's relevant here that "in the Compose environment" and "directly on a developer system" are different environments, and you will need a mechanism like environment variables to communicate these.  In the Compose environment you will need the database container's name and the default PostgreSQL port 5432; on a developer system you will typically need `localhost` as the host name and whichever port has been published.  You cannot hard-code this configuration in your application.

Comment: Hi. Very sorry for the delay. Please give me 24 hours. I'll share the details.